# Assign value to element of an array inside a loop in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to modify the value to an element of an array and I don't know the syntax to do it

```
for i in `seq 0 8`;
do
    if [ ${config[$i]} = "value1" ]
        then config[$i] = "value2"    #<- This line
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Technically, the only thing broken there is the whitespace. Don't put spaces around your operators in shell syntax:

```
config[$i]="value2"
```

However, there are lots of other little things you may want to think about. For example, if an element of `config` can contain whitespace, the test can break. Use quotes or the `[[` test keyword to avoid that.

```
… if [[ ${config[$i]} = "value1" ]]
    then config[$i]="value2" …
```

`seq` is a nonstandard external executable. You'd be better off using the builtin iteration syntax. Furthermore, assuming the iteration happens over all the elements in `config`, you probably just want to do:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#config[@]}; i++));
do
    if [[ ${config[$i]} = "value1" ]]
        then config[$i]="value2"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the 2 extra spaces like this:

```
config[$i]="value2"
```